# Shrinking/zipping url query parameters values

Tags: java, http, url, compression, query-string

Are there any worthwhile ways of shrinking a long query parameter down? Something like Base64 encoding but that reduces the # of characters.

Something like http://foo.com/bar.html?info=**this%20is%20some%20about%20something**&cat=**meow**

to some shrunk (zipped?) version where the bolded query param values are "shrunk"?  I still want to be able to unzip to read them on the other side.

This is more an excercise of shrinking the payload and not encrypting it.

The data can be totally random (generated by a end user) so I can't have a lookup table  approach.

Please note I say worthwhile, so minimal compression (<10%) isnt significant enough, is most important for longer strings (since im combatting query param length limits), should be performant enough there shrinking/unshrinking doesnt have a significant performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is intended for Javascript in the end, you can use HTML5 LocalStorage - this remains with the browser, independent of requests.

If the data is intended for server-side scripts, you can use session storage (that's what it's called in php, other languages may have other names.

If you are trying to make it look nicer in the address bar, I would suggest using POST rather than GET forms - the data is sent in it's entirety, but not shown in the address bar (and not subject to URL length limitations).

Comment: Due to the RESTful framework I'm working w/ it adds unnecessary complexity fo switch methods just to facilitate the transfer of data; which is why I'm asking this in the first place. 
I need a cross-browser solution (not just modern browsers) and shouldnt use Session state (REST-based platform with discrete app servers)